# Press enter on form input to make it lose focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have a form with an input box and hidden submit field:

```
<form action="javascript:void(0);">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit" style="display:none;">
</form>
```

I would like to make it so that when you click enter, the input box simply loses focus.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: [`.blur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/blur)

Comment: What do you mean by "click enter"? Clicks are done with a mouse. Keys are _pressed_. I suppose you mean, "press enter", but I'm not positive. Edit - your headline question is clearer - it seems you mean _press_ indeed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this out. Please note that you need to include jquery file for this to work.

```
<form action="javascript:void(0);">
    <input type="text" id="txtFocus">
    <input type="submit" style="display:none;" id="btnHidden">
</form>
<script>
$("#btnHidden").on('click', function() {
        $('#txtFocus').blur();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

Give your input an id for convenience, and you can do this with this little function using plain javascript

```
<form action="javascript:void(0);">
    <input id="input1" type="text">
    <input type="submit" style="display:none;">
</form>
<script>
document.getElementById('input1').addEventListener('keyup',function(e){
    if (e.which == 13) this.blur();
});
</script>
```

Comment: `.addEventListener('keydown',` would better resemble a regular form submission

Answer (score 2):

Avoid the ID lookup in the JS code by the following (tested on Firefox and Chrome). Submit by input loss of focus, possibly triggered by form submit.

```js
function myFunction(input) {
    input.value = input.value.toUpperCase();
    return false;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="this.textfield.blur();return false">
  <input type="text" id="textfield" onfocusout="myFunction(this)">
  <input type="submit" style="display:none;" />
</form>
```